# Add params to function to only execute if value matches name in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object:

```
const oData = { 
  name: 'Hound', 
  weapon: 'sword', 
  likes: 'Chicken, Arya, Revenge', 
  dislikes: 'Fire, Mountain, Lannisters'
};
```

which I pass to this function:

```
fConvertValuesToArrays(obj) {
    for (const i in obj) { 
      obj[i] = Array.isArray(obj[i]) ? obj[i] : [obj[i]]; 
    }
    return obj;
  },
```

This works as expected in converting all the values into arrays but I now need this to only execute if the value matches with any of the values in this array:

```
const aNamesToMatch = [ 'likes', 'dislikes' ];
```

Is it possible to work this into the function or do I need a separate function for this and call that function inside `fConvertValuesToArrays`?
If so how would that work?

I tried to add an if statement before the ternary but I did not work as expected:

```
fConvertValuesToArrays(obj) {
    for (const i in obj) { 
      if ( obj.likes || obj.dislikes ) {
        obj[i] = Array.isArray(obj[i]) ? obj[i] : [obj[i]];
      } 
    }
    return obj;
  },
```

Comment: if you know which members you want to convert, why do you loop on all members ? Call a function on the member itself only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `includes()` on the array `aNamesToMatch`. And check if current key is inside that array.

```js
const oData = { 
  name: 'Hound', 
  weapon: 'sword', 
  likes: 'Chicken, Arya, Revenge', 
  dislikes: 'Fire, Mountain, Lannisters'
};
const aNamesToMatch = [ 'likes', 'dislikes' ];
function fConvertValuesToArrays(obj,keys) {
   
    for (const i in obj) { 
      if (keys.includes(i)) {
        obj[i] = Array.isArray(obj[i]) ? obj[i] : [obj[i]];
      } 
    }
    return obj;
  }
console.log(fConvertValuesToArrays({...oData},aNamesToMatch))
```

Comment: Without IE support

Comment: perhaps he wondered to get `"likes": ["Chicken", "Arya", "Revenge"]...` by  `obj[i].split(", ")` instead of `[obj[i]]`

Comment: I am using `split` but I first do a check if it includes a `,` but this does not impact this question or answer. Thanks

Comment: @MaheerAli includes is not supported in IE

Comment: @iguypouf thanks for information. I didn't knew. But the browser support doesn't matter unless OP himself ask about it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping through the entire object, you can just loop through `aNamesToMatch`. Update each of those properties in the object to an array:

```js
const aNamesToMatch=['likes','dislikes'],
      oData={name:'Hound',weapon:'sword',likes:'Chicken, Arya, Revenge',dislikes:'Fire, Mountain, Lannisters'};

function fConvertValuesToArrays(obj, keys) {
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (!Array.isArray(obj[key]))
      obj[key] = [obj[key]]
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(fConvertValuesToArrays(oData, aNamesToMatch))
```

If there is a possibility of having a key in the array which doesn't exist in the object, you can check if the key exists in the object first:

```
if (key in obj && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
}
```

Comment: I like this idea but most of the time there won't be both `likes` and `dislikes` so this could send unnecessary data to the object.

Comment: @UXCODA you can check if the `key` exists first: `if (key in obj && !Array.isArray(obj[key]))`

Answer (score 1):

Make this change

```
if(i == 'likes' || i == 'dislikes')
  { 
  obj[i] = Array.isArray(obj[i]) ? obj[i] : [obj[i]]; 
  }
```

This will check if the key is likes/dislikes and creates an array only if that is the case.